# Unbounded wildcards vs Object type parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics

The [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) explains the difference between using Object as a type parameter and using and unbounded wildcard (?) by using the following code example:

```
    public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
        for (Object elem : list)
        System.out.println(elem + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

and

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
    for (Object elem: list)
    System.out.print(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

It says that the first example fails to achieve its goal of printing a list of any type. It can only print lists of Objects; it cannot print `List<Integer>`, `List<String>`, `List<Double>`, and so on, because they are not subtypes of `List<Object>`.

But surely Integer, String and Double are subtypes of Object? Doesn't everything inherit from Object in Java?

Comment: The first example only fails to achieve its goal of printing a list of any type because you can't call it with a list of any type as a parameter. If you were to do some subversive casting, it'd work just fine, [as shown here](http://ideone.com/dWTCur).

Comment: @AndyTurner Does _List<Object> objs = (List<Object>) (List) ints;_ First convert it to the raw List type, and thereafter to the parameterized List type?

I've found that replacing that line with _List objs = (List) myList;_ also works

Comment: Well, that works too, you're just keeping `objs` as a raw type, so the compiler will allow it as a parameter to any method expecting a generic list. I would advise making it a non-raw type, though, so that you have as much type checking as possible.